# Python: How to escape apostrophe in JSON?

Tags: python, json, pymysql

I have JSON data like `'Courses Offered': "Economics,World history: survey,Women's history,Other social science course"}`

Due to `Women's history` it gives error:

```
'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'s history,Other social science course"}]
```

I tried to replace `'` with `"''` but did not work

Comment: Have you tried adding ` \ ` backslash before quote?

Comment: You are building SQL by string concatenation. Don't do that. Ever. User parameters.

Comment: That's not valid JSON. JSON uses double quoted strings only.

Comment: @Tomalak it worked!!!

Comment: @Volatil3 Post the relevant code you have used, I'll upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Use an ORM or other means of inserting data into your database, such as query parameters, not string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

```
dic = {'Courses Offered': "Economics,World history: survey,Women's history,Other social science course"}
string = dic['Courses Offered'] 
print(re.sub(r'[\']',"\\'",string))
>>> Economics,World history: survey,Women\'s history,Other social science course
```

Comment: This may solve the immediate error but it's not the correct solution to the problem. SQL should never be built from strings. Parameters should be used in all cases. When parameters are used, no manipulation of values is necessary.